# Dynamics CRM, Ribbon Button, Add linked child entity

Tags: xml, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'm trying to add a button to the contact form which creates a child activity record linked to the parent contact.

I'm using the Ribbon Workbench to attempt this.
I've got the button showing successfully but I can't get the child record to be created.
The Ribbon Workbench won't publish the below xml

The XML I have so far is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<RibbonDiffXml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <CustomActions>
    <CustomAction Id="new.contact.Button1.Button.CustomAction" Location="Mscrm.Form.contact.MainTab.Actions.Controls._children" Sequence="19">
      <CommandUIDefinition>
        <Button Command="new.contact.Command0.Command" Description="Send SMS" Id="new.contact.Button1.Button" Image32by32="$webresource:new_sms32" Image16by16="$webresource:new_sms16" LabelText="$LocLabels:new.contact.Button1.Button.LabelText" Sequence="19" TemplateAlias="o1" ToolTipTitle="$LocLabels:new.contact.Button1.Button.ToolTipTitle"     ToolTipDescription="$LocLabels:new.contact.Button1.Button.ToolTipDescription" />
      </CommandUIDefinition>
    </CustomAction>
  </CustomActions>
  <Templates>
    <RibbonTemplates Id="Mscrm.Templates" />
  </Templates>
  <CommandDefinitions>
    <CommandDefinition Id="new.contact.Command0.Command">
      <EnableRules />
      <DisplayRules />
      <Actions>
        <JavaScriptFunction FunctionName="AddSMS" Library="$webresource:new_WFTrigger">
          <StringParameter Name="child" Value="new_sms" />
          <CrmParameter Name="parentRecordId" Value="PrimaryItemIds" />
          <CrmParameter Name="parente" Value="PrimaryEntityTypeCode" /> <!--The ribbon workbench refuses to fill the Name of this parameter and tries to publish it as blank -->
        </JavaScriptFunction>
          </Actions>
    </CommandDefinition>
  </CommandDefinitions>
  <RuleDefinitions>
    <TabDisplayRules />
        <DisplayRules />
    <EnableRules />
  </RuleDefinitions>
  <LocLabels>
    <LocLabel Id="new.contact.Button1.Button.LabelText">
      <Titles>
        <Title description="Send SMS" languagecode="1033" />
      </Titles>
    </LocLabel>
    <LocLabel Id="new.contact.Button1.Button.ToolTipTitle">
      <Titles>
        <Title description="Send SMS" languagecode="1033" />
      </Titles>
    </LocLabel>
    <LocLabel Id="new.contact.Button1.Button.ToolTipDescription">
      <Titles>
        <Title description="Send SMS" languagecode="1033" />
      </Titles>
    </LocLabel>
  </LocLabels>
</RibbonDiffXml>
```

And the javascript web resource I have is:

```
function AddSMS(child, parente, parentRecordId) {
    var url = Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl() + "main.aspx?etn= " + child + " &extraqs=%3f_CreateFromId%3d" + parentRecordId + "%26_CreateFromType%3d" + parente + "%26etn%" + child + " &pagetype=entityrecord";
open(url, 'Create SMS');
}
```

Update: a problem developed in my environment so I've started a new organisation to develop the cusomtisations. When I get back to the same point I'll come back to this thread. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There should be an error on the last page of the import screen that may help you deduce the problem.  It took me awhile to realize that the error log was even on that page.  If I remember correctly, it looks like a hyperlink.

Can you post the error message in that error log?

Comment: It just occurred to me that you are probably using the workbench instead of uploading a solution.  To do the troubleshooting step mentioned about you will need to [create a new Solution for your Ribbon](http://gtcrm.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/how-to-view-ribbon-definitions-in-crm-2011-3/) and merge your XML into it.

Answer (score 0):

The Ribbon Workbench does not publish the 'Name' attribute of JavaScriptFunction parameters since they are only used when adding Parameters to Url actions - so I don't think the problem is to do with this.

What error are you getting? Perhaps you could be getting a timeout - are you publishing to Dynamics CRM Online?